# JMeter - Ping authorization is showing Page Expired in authorization.ping

Tags: jmeter

Not able to do authorization for PING identity application with JMeter 5.4.1. On entering proper credentials and on submitting the request, it shows response as 'Page Expired' and  automatuc redirection is not happening. So not able to move further.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably passing only credentials is not sufficient, there should be some dynamic parameters which are the subject for the [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

Try recording the login flow twice using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and compare generated test plans, if you detect any differences - it means that there are dynamic parameters which need to be extracted from the previous response and passed to the next request

More information on the concept: [Advanced Load Testing Scenarios with JMeter: Part 1 - Correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations)

Also don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan

Comment: I found there is parameter changing in url and updated and sent request. Now one more redurection happened and its throwing now 403- forbidden error. I checked the response manualky using developer tool.. there i see header cookie is getting added with some session key.. which is not happening during JMeter execution.

Comment: Manualky on the same screen, it shows 302 response  code and then redirect to the loggged in page. Also in all screen Everytime it passes PF cookie.. which gets appended with session id in login screen response and also PA.dps cookie data is required.

Comment: Hi Dmitri.. on entering crdentials it has 3 redirections where in first response it sets PF cookie with some session in the header and then redirects to next by setting the cookie with updated one..then from the response header it takes the new cookie value for PA.dps and paas in the  2nd redirection request and then in 3rd redirection it lands on proper login page. This happens automatically while navigating thru application Manually. But in Jmeter in the first redirection where it has to pass the updated cookie value with session for PF cookie, it does not do that and shows up 403 - Forbidde